# Kinect SDK 1.8: How to detect grip using javascript?

Tags: javascript, kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect-interaction

I'm playing with javascript API of KINECT FOR WINDOWS SDK 1.8 starting from Webserver sample included in developer toolkot. Now i would like to detect grip interaction in browser and i've not result at the moment.
I'm using the [Handpointer interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn435616.aspx) which provide a property **isInGripInteraction** but it is always false and the property **handEventType** , that return the name of the most recent event triggered by the hand pointer, is always none.
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Did you find the solutiion?how?